# Best searching library for mobile database

Tags: android, search, objectbox

Currently, I am working on an android project with a huge data set that has over 1 million of entries. Something like below:

```
data class Point(var address: String, var location: Location)
```

I need to implement searching methods to search all over the entries' addresses. I tried to convert data set to `objectbox` database. However, the searching performance is not really so good as I expected although I indexed the address field. It took about 10s for each search query. Here's how I did query with objectBox:

```
val list = ObjectBox.box.query()
            .contains(Point_.address, keyword)
            .build()
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do a better performance search? Or perhaps a different search engine?

Comment: 10s for each query with ObjectBox?  I wonder if you find a better solution>

Comment: @LeoK yah, I had to use a full-text search library to make the performance better.

Comment: Thanks.  Care to share what library you use?

Comment: @LeoK I am using this library: https://github.com/lukhnos/lucenestudy/tree/f992866738da1d15c45db663c4ef3eb074adb65e. It's about 100ms for each query.

Comment: Thank you.  So it's a search engine?  Do you use a DB to store your data, or do you simply store them in plain files?  I actually use ObjectBox to manage over 500,000 text records.  The search of a piece of text is pretty interactive.  I didn't measure the speed, but it appears to react within a second.

Answer (score 0):

By default String queries in ObjectBox ignore case. If an index is used, it's better to use a case-sensitive query. This should perform magnitudes better. E.g.:

```
val list = ObjectBox.box.query()
            .contains(Point_.address, keyword, StringOrder.CASE_SENSITIVE)
            .build()
```